# Minecraft Server doesn't let others connect when running the .jar using java (instead of javaw)

Tags: networking, java, port-forwarding, ipv6, minecraft

I'm running a small Minecraft server using ipv6. The relevant port has been forwarded in both the firewall and the router. My friends are able to connect to the server correctly, BUT ONLY if the file is run using "javaw" instead of the normal java. I'm functionally forced to doubleclick the .jar file instead of using cmd or powershell when starting the server if i want others to join. The downside to this is that I don't have access to the server console while people from outside the local Network are playing on the server. To summarize:

```
javaw -jar server.jar
```

running this allows people to connect from outside the local network, however I can't use the console

```
java -jar server.jar
```

running this allows me to connect and use the console, but others cannot join.

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using a dynDNS since ipv6 addresses are a pain to deal with. ipv4 is not an option, because my ISP forces me to use a DS-Lite tunnel. Note that when using javaw, my friends can connect using either the dyndns-domain or my public ipv6. either works.

There are no errors in the log. login attempts are not displayed in the console when running java. running the cmd window with admin privileges doesn't make a difference.

I've tried using the official .jar and the papermc .jar and encountered this issue in both.

I used this site to check my ports:
https://port.tools/port-checker-ipv6/

While the server is being ran using javaw, other people are able to connect and the port is open.
While the server is being ran using java, the site says "Resource temporarily unavailable".
Not doing anything with the port will result in the site displaying "ressource temporarily unavailable" as well.
running a normal http server (using python) on that port will result in it being displayed as open.

I'm not very knowledgeable on java and I honestly have no clue where to start troubleshooting this issue, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Update: My firewall was messing with java.exe, but not with javaw. Pretty obvious in hindsight. I fixed it by just creating a new rule.